# setting bit rates in creating video from images in ffmpeg not working

Tags: video, image-processing, ffmpeg

I have a HQ video of one second

Some information of this video is as below

```
Dimensions : 1920 x 1080    
Codec : H.264    
Framerate : 30 frames per second    
Size : 684.7 kB (6,84,673 bytes)
Bitrates : 5458 kbps
```

I have extracted frames from video

```
ffmpeg -i f1.mp4 f%d.jpg
```

All images are of **1920 x 1020 pixels** by default 30 frames are generated (f7_1.jpg, f7_2.jpg,.....,f7_30.jpg)

I have added some texts and objects to these images (without changing dimensions of any image, all 30 images are still of **1920 x 1020 pixels**)

Now I am trying to merge all these images to create single video (of 1 second)

I referred [this](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#See-Also) official document, I have run below command

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i f7_%d.jpg -r 30 -b:v 5458k foo_5458_2.mp4
```

Video created is also of one second, thing is its bit rates are higher then the original one. New video has **6091 kbps** bit rates, while I expect are **5458 kbps** only.

Because of higher bits, its gets finish very quickly compare to original video in video player.

Is there any thing  I missing ??

And I don't know what is exact meaning and job of `-f image2` option, when I run command without this option, I am getting same video.

Answer (score 0):

JPG is not a lossless codec. Perhaps try again with PNG

```
ffmpeg -i f1.mp4 f%d.png
```

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/58f0adc/scripts/ff-sequence.sh#L23)

Comment: Don't mind, may I know what will be the difference ?? 
there is huge code I have written on calculation of coordinates of jpg files ??, I will need to change if dimensions will be changed

Comment: The difference is that each time you encode JPG you will experience generation loss http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss

Comment: Thanks @Steven Penny, Now all images are of size 2+ MB, some are of 2.1mb, some are of 2.4mb and all, unique thing among these images is all are of 1920x1080 dimensions.

Comment: I run same command - `ffmpeg -f image2 -i f7_%d.png -r 30 -b:v 5458k foo_5458_2.mp4`   and now bit rate is still in the picture, new bit rates of video is 4832 kbps

Comment: I reached some what near to goal by explicitly specifying number of frames. `ffmpeg -f image2 -i f7_%d.png -r 30 -b:v 5458k foo_1.mp4` generates video with bit rates **4832 kbps** and `ffmpeg -f image2 -r 30 -i f7_%d.png -r 30 -b:v 5458k foo_2.mp4` generates video with bit rates **5150 kbps**, gives me somewhat good experience compare to foo_1.mp4 in video player. Feeling a little bit happy